Facing DioException: HttpException: Connection closed while receiving data in Flutter when adding token to header
I am trying to call an API in Flutter using the Dio package, but I encounter the following error when adding a token to the header:
If I remove the token, the function works correctly. The token is valid because it works with other endpoints and the endpoint in question works correctly in Postman. I have tried several solutions such as:

Unchecking the Android Studio proxy settings
Adding keep-alive settings

However, none of these solutions have worked. Here is the code I am using:
code
I have verified that:
The token is correctly formatted.
The endpoint and token work in Postman.
I have tried with and without keep-alive settings.
Could someone help me identify what might be causing this issue or suggest any other solutions?

Try to put your code in try-catch block to identify error.

I make that but if you catch the error you dont solve it , when i catch the error  it print in the consle   Error: HttpException: Connection closed while receiving data, @
DroidFlutter i catch the error usin on DioException

Please share the code you tried.

https://i.sstatic.net/IjklHAWk.png

i add a url picture for my code @DroidFlutter

Your code is up to date. Try some solution hope it works for you. - 1) https://i.sstatic.net/Uj4Kb.png, 2) Adjust the timeout settings in your Dio client to allow for longer connection and data receiving durations. 3)Update Dio and Dependencies

To check that it isn't a server incompatibility, use Postman again, but this time set the name of the token to authorization (lowercase A). This is what Dart will do, so it's important to compare exactly with Postman. (Note that the server should accept the lowercase a, but some do not.)
